# Force numbering of amsmath `equation*`?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

Is it possible to force an automatic equation number in an amsmath `equation*` environment? Something like

```
\begin{equation*} \dotag
x^2
\end{equation*}
```

where the effect of `\dotag` is to transform `equation*` into `equation`?

I looked at `amsmath.sty`

```
\renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newenvironment{equation*}{%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

and saw that the difference between the unstarred and the starred version is an additional command `\incr@eqnum`, but adding this code to the `equation*` environment in my document doesn't work.

Background: The preferred way to include display math in Pandoc's markdown is to enclose them in a pair of `$$`. For LaTeX output, they are translated into `\[` and `\]`, and since `amsmath` is included in the default template, these act like an `equation*` environment. There are workarounds, but this way has several advantages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? I use `\incr@eqnum`, as you suggest, but also add the equation number via `\tag`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dotag{\incr@eqnum\tag{\number\value{equation}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} \dotag
x^2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
y^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*} \dotag
z^2
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or just renew the definition of the `equation*` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{equation*}{%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
x^2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
y^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*} 
z^2
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of `\makeatletter`, or more precisely, never quite understood what it does.